# Join C# EF6 lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, join

Estou com um problema, estou fazendo um join com C# com EF6, Tenho duas tabelas não relacionadas `Invest` e `Encarteiramento` e preciso fazer um join em `Invest` onde agencia e conta seja igual a, agencia e conta de `Encarteiramento` e o matricula do consultor seja igual a pessoa logada. A matricula do consultor já recebo normalmente. Segue meu código.

```cs
var resultado = _context.Invest.Join(_context.Encarteiramento,
                inv => new { agencia = inv.AGENCIA, conta = inv.CONTA },
                enc => new { agencia = enc.Agencia, conta = enc.Conta },
                (inv, enc) => new { inv, enc })
                .Where(result => result.enc.Matricula == matriculaConsultor);
```

SQL Gerado

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[AGENCIA] AS [AGENCIA], 
    [Extent1].[Vlr_Evento] AS [Vlr_Evento], 
    [Extent1].[CONTA] AS [CONTA], 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
    [Extent2].[TIP_CLIENTE] AS [TIP_CLIENTE], 
    [Extent2].[CPF] AS [CPF], 
    [Extent2].[DATA] AS [DATA], 
    [Extent2].[Agencia] AS [AGENCIA1], 
    [Extent2].[Conta] AS [CONTA1], 
    [Extent2].[AG_PRINC] AS [AG_PRINC], 
    [Extent2].[CONTA_PRINC] AS [CONTA_PRINC], 
    [Extent2].[CONSULTOR] AS [CONSULTOR], 
    [Extent2].[Matricula] AS [Matricula], 
    [Extent2].[EQUIPE_RESPONSAVEL] AS [EQUIPE_RESPONSAVEL], 
    [Extent2].[EQUIPE_MESA] AS [EQUIPE_MESA], 
    [Extent2].[DIR_REG_AG_PRINC] AS [DIR_REG_AG_PRINC], 
    [Extent2].[GER_REG_AG_PRINC] AS [GER_REG_AG_PRINC]
    FROM  [dbo].[Investfacil] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Encarteiramento] AS [Extent2] ON (([Extent1].[AGENCIA] = [Extent2].[Agencia]) OR (([Extent1].[AGENCIA] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[Agencia] IS NULL))) AND (([Extent1].[CONTA] = [Extent2].[Conta]) OR (([Extent1].[CONTA] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[Conta] IS NULL)))
    WHERE [Extent2].[Matricula] = @p__linq__0
```

Quando removo as perter de **([Extent1].[AGENCIA] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[Agencia] IS NULL)**. Consigo obter os resultados corretamente, entretando não sei o porque ele está gerando a query neste formato. Como consigo resolver este problema?

Desde já agradeço pela atenção.

Comment: agencia e conta estão com qual tipagem? ao meu ver está certo, essa checagem é normal no ef, é uma checagem pra nulo

Comment: @Lucas Miranda, era exatamente isso mesmo, no meu banco eles estavam como nulo, o que não fazia sentido pois esse campo não pode ser nulo. Alterei a tabela e agora esta funcionando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, no meu caso o problema estava no banco pois estas colunas tinham que ser **not null** e estavam como nulas e assim dava erro na hora de buscar, alterei todas para **not null** e agora esta funcionando.